# How can i output the frequency of a substring in order of popularity?

Tags: c++, string

I have a program that accepts a list of email addresses and i am trying to output the domains in order of their popularity. The program takes input from the user and  then outputs how many domains have been inserted. This is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
std::vector<std::string> addresses;
int count = 0;


    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "Insert an e-mail address " << std::endl;
        std::string address;
        if (!getline(std::cin, address) || address.empty())break;
        addresses.push_back(address);

        int pos = address.find("@");
        std::string sub = address.substr(pos + 1);

        while (pos != std::string::npos)
        {

            count++;
            pos = address.find("@", pos + 1);


        }


    }

        std::cout<<"Number of domains:"  << count << std::endl;


    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you are most likely looking for `std::map<std::string,unsigned>` that lets you count frequencies easily